# SQL Server: Why does 'DBCC Page' report 'Tinyint' is 2 byetes?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, dbcc

I tried to figured out how SQL Server stores `Tinyint` (which is supposed to be 1-byte long) column.

```
-- Create table
CREATE TABLE MyTest.dbo.TempTable
(
    Col1 Tinyint NOT NULL
);

-- Fill it up
INSERT INTO dbo.TempTable VALUES (3);

-- Get page info
dbcc ind
(
'MyTest'                 /*Database Name*/
,'dbo.TempTable' /*Table Name*/
,-1 /*Display information for all pages of all indenxes*/
);

-- Get page data
dbcc traceon(3604)
dbcc page
(
'MyTest' /*Database Name*/
,1      /*File ID*/
,182 /*Page ID*/
,3     /*Output mode: 3 - display page header and row details */
)
```

**Here is the result:**

---

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

PAGE: (1:182)
...
...
...

Slot 0 Offset 0x60 **Length 9**

Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP **Record Size = 9**

Memory Dump @0x000000000545A060

0000000000000000:   **10000600 03000100 00**†††††††††††††††††.........

Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0x4 Length 2 Length (physical) 2

Col1 = 3

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

---

**Interpretation:**
The actual data row is 10 00 0600 0300 0100 00 as: 
10: Status bits A 
00: Status bit B
0600: Position where number of columns is stored 
0300: Tinyint data 
0100: Number of column 
00: Null bitmap 
**Total bytes:** 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 9 bytes 
 
**Comparing with 'Smallint':** 
Altering 'Col1' type to '`Smallint`' (which is 2-byte long) produced **exactly** the same result. 

**Question**
Why does SQL Server dedicate 2 bytes to '`Tinyint`' column? Why doesn't it distinguish between 'Tinyint' and 'Smallint' in store size?

Comment: the extra byte can be attributed to Null bitmap...more explanation here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14774/sql-server-storage-of-tinyint

Comment: Even better, see paragraph "Smallest Row Size" http://jongurgul.com/blog/sql-server-row-internals/

Comment: @nshah Your second comment is the answer. This is all about minimum row size (9 bytes) and padding. I wished you posted it as an answer to enable me choose it as the Best Answer. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the output of DBCC PAGE WITH TABLERESULTS.

When I put in two rows, one with all 0 and one with all 1, I can clearly see the tinyint field is using only one byte:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SpaceTest
    (
      biggest BIGINT ,
      medium INT ,
      small SMALLINT ,
      tiny TINYINT
    )
INSERT  INTO dbo.SpaceTest
        ( biggest, medium, small, tiny )
VALUES  ( 0, 0, 0, 0 ),
        ( 1, 1, 1, 1 )

--Get a list of pages used by the table
DBCC IND('Sandbox', 'SpaceTest',0)
```

[image: Output of DBCC IND]

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604);
DBCC PAGE (Sandbox,1,42823,3) WITH tableresults;
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Your case derivatives from my question so much that cannot be seen as a counter example. It is about minimum row size and padding. See [link](http://jongurgul.com/blog/sql-server-row-internals).